# Quickest way to to get fraction of rows with column = some value in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe

A Pandas `df` has a column called `Target`.

This is my solution `len(df[df['Target'] == 1])/len(df)` which works, but would like to know if there is a faster way

Comment: one can also take a sum of the boolean instead of masking the df and then taking length try : `df['Target'].eq(1).sum()/len(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shape function of the dataframe objects.

```
df[df['Target'] == 1].shape[0]/df.shape[0]
```

After submitting my answer, I got curious about the timing and decided to check it.

I run this code:

```
import time
for test in range(5):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    # My solution 
    def myfunc1():
        df[df["A"] == 1].shape[0]/df.shape[0]
    # Your solution
    def myfunc2():
        len(df[df['A'] == 1])/len(df)
    # @anky solution
    def myfunc3():
        df['A'].eq(1).sum()/len(df)

    n = 10000
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(n): myfunc1()
    t1 = time.time()

    t2 = time.time()
    for i in range(n): myfunc2()
    t3 = time.time()

    t4 = time.time()
    for i in range(n): myfunc3()
    t5 = time.time()

    total_1 = t1-t0
    total_2 = t3-t2
    total_3 = t5-t4
    print(test, ":", total_1, total_2, total_3)
```

and this is the print out:

0 : 4.102828025817871 4.083608150482178 2.5046629905700684

1 : 4.065492868423462 4.055856943130493 2.534034252166748

2 : 4.093224287033081 4.119946002960205 2.5002260208129883

3 : 4.10286808013916 4.086605072021484 2.5362727642059326

4 : 4.023838996887207 4.006290912628174 2.4990227222442627

As you can see @anky is the fastest, the other two depend on the dataset